# Dual booting two windows 7

Tags: boot, partitioning, multi-boot

I've installed two windows 7 in my pc and during the 2nd windows 7 install, i lost my D drive(windows setup deleted that partition). I recovered it and got all data back. Now for some reasons, I want to reinstall the newly installed windows 7. But I'm scared and I don't want to lose data again. Somebody please tell me why windows setup deleted my D partition earlier so that i can avoid that this time. This is the details of current partitions.

1. C: Old Windows 7 partition(primary)
2. E: Data partition (primary)
3. G: New dual boot windows 7 partition-logical(I want to delete this windows and reinstall windows here)
4. System reserved(logical)
5. New volume H(logical drive- lost and recovered partition)

So my question is, if I try to install windows 7 again to that G drive, will windows delete one of my other partitions? If yes,  how to avoid it?

Comment: I don't know why that D: gets deleted, but take a backup of your imp files, and check this tutorials to make a proper installing of two windows 7 -http://www.howtogeek.com/214477/how-to-dual-boot-two-or-more-versions-of-windows/